# Handle back action for multiple view

Tags: android

I have an activity which have multiple piece of UI panel(you can think them as view in android), these panels will be invisible by default.

Now when user trigger `action1`, `PanelA` will display, when trigger `action2`, `PanelB` will display(at different location of the screen).

Both `PanelA` and `PanelB` is visible at the moment, now when user hit the back menu, the `PanelB` should disappear, and `PanelA` should disappear when hit the back menu again.

At first, I use `View` to hold different panels, however I found it is difficult to keep the state consist, for example, the activity will be a little different between `PanelA` and `PanelB`.

Then I found the fragment, however after I tried and tested, I found that the `addTobackStack()` can not apply to my us-case, since the `PanelA` and `PanelB` are at different location, android can not save their state by default.

So I wonder if there is any other solution for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually handle this scenario inside `onBackPressed()` method of an `Activity`.

For instance -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (panelB.isOpened()) {
        panelB.close()
    } else if (panelA.isOpened()) {
        panelA.close()         
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

When panelB is opened, it will close only panelB and wont do anything else. Same goes for panelA, if its opened and when both the panel are closed then it will exit the app like normal.

I highly recommend to use DialogFragments here as you can call `show()` and `dismiss()` any point of time on that and they can handle custom views pretty well.

Hope it helps.